# Maven unpack dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a dependency zip and jar files in my POM and have unpack-dependencies plugin in the same POM. Now when I try to build I get compilation errors for missing classes that belong in those zip and jar. Can it be that these classes in zip and jar are still not unpacked and the compile executes before unpack?
Did anyone come across similar issue? Any solutions appreciated.
I can unzip the file in the output directory as a jsr, but maven build can not see that as it is not in the repository and compilation fails.

My POM looks like this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>abc.xyx.com.prov</groupId>
      <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>abc.xyx.com.prov</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <includes>**/*.jar</includes> 
                        <version>2.1</version>
                        <outputDirectory>target/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please share more details, most importantly your pom or at least the dependency plugin configuration

Comment: A.Di Matteo, I just updated my post with example.

Comment: Maybe you should use `<outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>`, since your Java sources need those classes for compilation? The correct way to do this however seems to be using either `mvn install:install-file` to install your dependency to local repo, or use a central repository to download it from.